# Powershell XML Export-csv not appending a Hash

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting

I am fairly new to Powershell, I have rather weird xml according to me, My main objective is to convert the XML into CSV, where it ll be further used to sync to a database.
I have used the Powershell code to extract the xml into a hash.
Now I have problem converting them into CSV. The Export-csv writes only the last entry in the hash. Not sure why this, i checked few other forums, they say the -append feature in Export-csv is with powershell 3.0 only, i am using 1.0..

**can you help me out of this ?**

XML :

```
<catalog>
<segment>
<segmentname>Batch</segmentname>
<hosts>
<host>
<hostname>cglist17</hostname>
</host>
<host>
<hostname>cglist18</hostname>
</host>
<host>
<hostname>cglist19</hostname>
</host>
<host>
<hostname>cglist20</hostname>
</host>
</hosts>
</segment>
<segment>
<segmentname>Custom S2</segmentname>
<hosts>
<host>
<hostname>cglist21</hostname>
</host>
<host>
<hostname>cglist22</hostname>
</host>
</hosts>
</segment>
<segment>
<segmentname>eCommerce</segmentname>
<hosts>
<host>
<hostname>cglist09</hostname>
</host>
<host>
<hostname>cglist10</hostname>
</host>
</hosts>
</segment>
</catalog>
```

Powershell Code :

```
[xml]$xd=gc "C:\Users\sxa8869\Desktop\Webserv\segmentcat.xml"
$nodelist = $xd.selectnodes("/catalog/segment")

$MasterArray = @()
$MasterArray = "" | Select segmentname,hosts

$file="C:\Users\sxa8869\Desktop\Webserv\sha.csv"

foreach ($node in $nodelist) {

  $hostsNode = $node.selectSingleNode("hosts")
  $segmentname = $node.selectSingleNode("segmentname")
  $MasterArray.segmentname=$segmentname.get_InnerXml()
  foreach ($hostitem in $hostsNode) {
    $hostnamenodes = $hostitem.selectnodes("host")
    foreach ($hostname in $hostnamenodes) {
      $MasterArray.hosts=$hostname.selectSingleNode("hostname").get_InnerXml()

#- Displays the hash in table format, want this format in csv
         $MasterArray        

# - displaying only the last element
      $MasterArray | export-csv "file.csv" -notype      

# - this works, but i want to use export-csv to get it in this format
 '"'+$MasterArray.segmentname+'"'+","+'"'+$MasterArray.hosts+'"'    

    }     
  } 
} 


Required output :-
 -----------------
"segmentname","hosts"
"Batch","cglist17"
"Batch","cglist18"
"Batch","cglist19"
"Batch","cglist20"
"Custom S2","cglist21"
"Custom S2","cglist22"
"eCommerce","cglist09"
eCommerce,"cglist10"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're overly complicating things. Try this:

```
$myXML = [xml](Get-Content "C:\Users\sxa8869\Desktop\Webserv\segmentcat.xml")
$file="C:\Users\sxa8869\Desktop\Webserv\sha.csv"

$myArray = @()
foreach ($s in $myXML.catalog.segment)
{
    foreach ($h in $s.hosts.host)
    {
        $myArray += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{"Segment Name" = $s.segmentname; "Host Name" = $h.hostname}
    }
}

$myArray | Export-Csv $file -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, works great.. you have minimised the line of code which makes it al the more efficient.. But just want to know is the best way to parse xml, i see many methods in stackoverflow.. `$myArray` - what will call this? Array, hasharray, Mutildimensional Array ??

Comment: The "best" way is the way you prefer. xpath and the "property way" (like the one above) all do the same thing. In this case, `$myArray = @()`, then it's called an "array"

Comment: As Graimer implied, there are multiple "best" ways of doing things. Do you want the most readable, the best performing, or what? I tend to favor readability, unless I've found a particular bottleneck. However, readability is very subjective, depending on what you're already familiar with.

Comment: Hey @KevinD & Graimer..need to do small change in this.. I want to rename the header of the CSV to "Segment Name" And "Host name".. Is this possible.. its like changing the Array variable name, and variable names cannot contain spaces.. Please reply asap, need to submit this by tonight..

Comment: see updated answer. If you read the code, you would probably have seen where to change this yourself. Please try at least before asking. You usually need to tweak the solutions you get here on SO to fit your situation. We are not a consulting company. ^^

Comment: NO actually i tried it with a varaible.. Eg "Var Name" = "text" which didnt work,and no prog language allows spaces in variabled.. so was assuming the property will not have that feature.. SO thought too complicated :(

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems here. 1st, you create an array `MasterArray`, but then you set it equal to a custom object that you create with `Select`. Now `MasterArray` is not an array anymore, but a single `pscustomobject`. 2nd, you set the values to the single objects properties, which overwrites the last entry every time. An array need to include multiple objects. I've rewritten it. I didn't improve it by using pipelines etc. but simply fixed your errors, ;-)  Script:

```
[xml]$xd = gc "C:\Users\sxa8869\Desktop\Webserv\segmentcat.xml"
$nodelist = $xd.selectnodes("/catalog/segment")

$MasterArray = @()

$file="C:\Users\sxa8869\Desktop\Webserv\sha.csv"

foreach ($node in $nodelist) {

    $hostsNode = $node.SelectSingleNode("hosts")
    $segmentname = $node.SelectSingleNode("segmentname")
    #Store static value for all objects in $node
    $segname = $segmentname.InnerText

    foreach ($hostitem in $hostsNode) {
        $hostnamenodes = $hostitem.SelectNodes("host")
        foreach ($hostname in $hostnamenodes) {
            #Add hostrecord to array
            $MasterArray += New-Object psobject -Property @{
            "Segment Name" = $segname
            "Host Name" = $hostname.InnerText
            }
        }
    }
}

#Output to console
$MasterArray        

#Save to file (path in $file variable  =  "...\sha.csv").
#Using Select-Object to specify order of columns
$MasterArray | Select-Object "Segment Name", "Host Name" | Export-Csv $file -NoTypeInformation
```

Output in "sha.csv":

```
"Segment Name","Host Name"
"Batch","cglist17"
"Batch","cglist18"
"Batch","cglist19"
"Batch","cglist20"
"Custom S2","cglist21"
"Custom S2","cglist22"
"eCommerce","cglist09"
"eCommerce","cglist10"
```

Comment: `$MasterArray += New-Object psobject -Property @{ SegmentName = $segname Host = $hostname.InnerText }`    @Graimer : That was great! worked perfect.. But i want to learn more. Will you be kind some of my basic questions? Correct me if im wrong..

Comment: My questions are on the line i have mentioned.. First i understand += add elements into the array, is this the only way to add them ??..  when i print my $MasterArray, why does it print host column first and then segementname.. Im sorry if these are basic questions, i wish to learn from the basics of this.

Comment: `+=` is the best way. You have a method called `Add()` BUT it will always fail. Arrays are fixed sizes and can't add elements. To add elements, you need to create a new array containing the old array's values and the new value(this is done in memory) and then save it as a variable(e.g. overwrite the old array). That's what `+=` does. Arrays doesn't have a fixed column order, so the output is "random". Use `$array | Format-Table(or Format-List) -Property Column1, Column2 etc.` to set your order. If you have more questions, search here on SO. Most basic question are answered before.

Comment: Hey @KevinD & Graimer..need to do small change in this.. I want to rename the header of the CSV to "Segment Name" And "Host name".. Is this possible.. its like changing the Array variable name, and variable names cannot contain spaces.. Please reply asap, need to submit this by tonight..

Comment: see updated answer. propeties can include spaces, just quote the name, like `$object.'This Property'`

Comment: So after 2 years this stopped being the correct answer? WTF?